# Handling Rename backup folders based on current date in SSIS?

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I want to create SSIS package which will take backup of files and copied into new location. I have to keep the backup history like

```
Day1
Day2
Day3
Day4
Day5
Day6
Day7
```

On the 8th Day, Day7 folder has to be renamed as "Week1". It means one week old data. Similarly week folders should get add on by each week.

```
 Week1
 Week2
 Week3
 Week4
```

Again "Week4" has to be renamed as "Month1". Later I have to delete Month3 folder when its older than 3 months.

I know its bit complex requirement, I'm done with the copying the files but not sure how to rename the folders based on days...

Any thoughts/Comments... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please visit [ask] and [mcve], add some code to your question. If all these folders will be in one directory then it is pretty simple. you are missing lot's of logic still. What happens when you reached 3rd month and start deleting? 8th day will be called week 2 day 1? then month 2 week 2 day 2? Maybe consider different format like W14D3 (Week 14 D3) That would be even easier to do.

Comment: Yes, All the folders are in same directory. But I'm not sure on what basis i will rename the folders. As of now, I'm just checking the folders in descending order Day7-->Week and Day6-->Day7...etc. Will this method work?

Comment: Some months only have 4 weeks, others have 5 weeks - how do you propose resolving this with your naming "convention"?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you push back against the specifications. Instead, propose that you will name the files with the date they were backedup/copied out. This greatly simplifies your problem, the amount of testing that is required and it becomes a much easier matter to determine age

Answer (score 1):

You can rename folders with a Script Task using the FileSystemObject.

Comment: I didnt made that. Yes I'm using script task by using FileSystemObject. I'm able to get list of folders and loop it. But I don't know how to rename the folders based on what conditions. Do i need to consider the current date and rename the folders based on that or how it will be?

Answer (score 0):

You can rename folders - in a fashion - using the File System Editor... Create then move content then delete the old... but it is not straightforward.